# how to call jquery in append javascript

Tags: jquery, cakephp

so i have to append() a page into an div# but i have problem, when i call a page and append it into a div#, the jquery and the bootstraps doesn't call, so the page i append() is messy.

i append() it like this :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo Router::url('/'); ?>admin/thisController/upload_page",
  dataType : 'html',
  cache: false,
  success : function(html){
    $('#DATA_UPLOAD').append(html);
  }
});
```

and when i call the jquery and bootstraps in the page that i append, it's make the page load twice a jquery and bootstraps, so all of the page becomes messy.

> so my question is there any other way to make the page append but
>   using the bootstraps and jquery from the page it's call (parent page)?

Comment: Your code looks pretty much correct to me.
But I think the issue is you want to attach an html page not a view or component.
which means you will now have 2 `<html>` `<head>` and `<body>`
How about you change your approach to using `<iframe>`
That way you can safely embed one html page into another.

Answer (score 0):

Use `html()` insted of append().
The `append()` method inserts specified content at the end of the selected elements, 
The `html()` method sets or returns the content (innerHTML) of the selected elements.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "<?php echo Router::url('/'); ?>admin/thisController/upload_page",
   dataType : 'html',
   cache: false,
   success : function(html){
      $('#DATA_UPLOAD').html(html);
   }
});
```

Comment: i already try using html() but it's the same, the style of bootstraps not affected on the page i append()